# Autenticação OAuth com Volley

Tags: android

Como posso fazer uma requisição a um WebService que usa OAuth como autenticação, sendo que uso a API Volley no Android ?

Comment: O que já tentou?

Comment: Olha, requisição apenas com Volley sem o OAuth já ta pronta, funcionando certinho... a minha dúvida é de como faço a requisição com o Volley junto ao OAuth.. Meu WebService já adaptei para permitir o OAuth, fiz uma aplicação java com o Client Jersey e o OAuth e funcionou. Minha dúvida é usar o OAuth junto ao Volley no Android..